# Local XML namespace definition not working as I expected

Tags: xslt, xml-namespaces, xalan

I'm processing an XMI document exported from ArgoUML.  It has elements of the form

`<UML:DataType href='http://argouml.org/profiles/uml14/default-uml14.xmi#-84-17--56-5-43645a83:11466542d86:-8000:000000000000087C'/>`

which points to an item of the form

```
<UML:DataType xmi.id="-84-17--56-5-43645a83:11466542d86:-8000:000000000000087C"
              name="Integer"
              isSpecification="false"
              isRoot="false"
              isLeaf="false"
              isAbstract="false"/>
```

I've already declared xmlns:UML="org.omg.xmi.namespace.UML" at the top of the xslt file.  I think I should be using something like :

```
<xsl:variable name="typeref" select="@href"/>
<xsl:variable name="ns" select='substring-before($typeref, "#")'/>
<xsl:variable name="identifier" select='substring-after($typeref, "#")'/>
<xsl:value-of xmlns:UML="$ns" 
              select='//UML:DataType[@xmi.id="$identifier"]/@name'/>
```

to deduce that my UML attributes type is Integer but this gives me

> `SystemId Unknown; Line #136; Column #94; A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.`

If I change the xmlns to AAA then I get no error but an empty tag.  I'm using Xalan2 on Debian squeeze.  What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see the syntax error. But it looks like you are trying to make a dynamic namespace declaration with `xmlns:UML="$ns"`. Why? Besides this is not posible, I don't think is useful in your case.

Comment: I agree with the previous answer, what is the proposed purpose for the (invalid) namespace-prefix specification for xmlns:UML="$ns"  ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't mind me.  Just making the classic mistake of conflating namespaces and URIs.  What I really needed was <xsl:value-of select='document($ns)//UML:DataType[@xmi.id=$identifier]/@name'/>